# Fetch entities with 0 junction tables

Tags: breeze

We have a few different entities. To explain a little better, here is example structure:

We have a lot of students.
We have a lot of homeworks.
Each homework has N (varies per homework) tasks.
There is a junction table connecting students and tasks.

We want to assign some tasks to certain students in a homework. Let's say one homework has 5 possible tasks, we want each student to get one or more tasks.

At the moment, interface lists all students with some properties (for this case let's say - average grade, hair colour, name, gender etc.) and has 5 checkboxes (there are 5 tasks in selected homework). We can use filters to show only students with average grade of 4, or just female students etc.

After a while, you would assign 98% of students, but you notice there are 2% students without any tasks for selected homework (some statistics shows you that). Instead of going through all few thousand students, we'd like to create filter which would use existing filters AND apply additional filter which would show all students which have 0 tasks where task.homeworkId = X

Right now, in my head there is a possible solution, but I'm not sure if this is possible using breeze:

```
from students 
    where (OLD_FILTERS)
       and ((from junction_table 
           where task.homeworkId = selectedHomeworkId
                 and student.id = $parent_query.id).count() = 0)
```

I've been over this for a while now, can't come up with a nice clean solution. Only thing comming to my mind is pretty complex solution with manual filtering of all student properties and this new condition on server.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Tables are related as follows:

student - junction table = 1 to many

task - junction table = 1 to many (basically, it's many-to-many student-task through junction entity)

task - homework = many to 1 (many tasks per one homework)

some perception on the model:

```
Student:
   Id
   Property1
   Property2
   ...

Homework
   Id
   Property1...

Task
   Id
   HomeworkId   // this is foreign key
   Property....


JunctionTable
   Id
   TaskId   // foreign key
   StudentId   // foreign key
```

Comment: Breeze can compose complex queries. I know this doesn't directly answer your question but I'd just like to direct you to http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples and see if anything might fit your need. If you're still struggling with how to compose your complex queries, perhaps you can give me more details as to how these different tables are related (as in, for example, the type of relationships (1-to-many, many-to-many, etc) ).

Comment: I've been through documentation few times now, nothing there helps me. We already have a lot of complex queries, but this is something we didn't manage to get working. I've added some explanation at the end of question, hope it explains a few things.

Comment: Something doesn't quite connect here. I didn't see any relation between `Student` and `Homework`, and to go from `Student` to `Homework`, one would have to navigate from `Student -> StudentTask (pretend this is the name of the Junction Table) -> Task -> Homework`. So if a `Student` doesn't have any `Task`, it won't have any `Homework`. But this is what you're trying to find out by comparing `task.homeworkId = selectedHomeworkId`. Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: That is correct. Are you suggesting I should have StudentHomework junction table as well? It would be a many-to-many relation.. It adds no value whatsoever... Correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: Well, with the current model, a `Student` with 0 `Task` means `student.studentTasks` collection count is 0. So you can create the following query to do this. `var pred = breeze.Predicate.create("studentTasks", "any", "id", "!=", null).not();` `var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Students').where(pred);`. I guess I'm still not understanding how `Homework` comes into play.

Comment: That is the one! We were working on this project for almost a year and didn't update Breeze. Unless I'm wrong, version 1.4.6 introduced that option. `var pred = breeze.Predicate.create("studentTasks", "any", "task.homeworkId", "==", homeworkId).not();` - that is how homework comes into play. Thank you!!!

Comment: Please mark this question as answered so we don't look again and Denis gets credit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DenisK for help. We used older version of Breeze without the needed option. Solution is simple predicate:

```
var pred = breeze.Predicate.create("studentTasks", "any", "task.homeworkId", "==", homeworkId).not();
```